# Can Leaflet jump to new world copy on zoom instead of just on panning?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

The markers will appear on the map if I pan the map, but if I zoom out and then zoom in on a copy of the map without the markers, they will not appear until I pan again.

Is it possible to change this so that zooming in and out will cause the markers to recalculate on the map?

```js
L.map('map', {
  'center': [0, 0],
  'zoom': 0,
  'worldCopyJump': true,
  'layers': [
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      'attribution': 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors'
    }),
    L.marker([0, -135]),
    L.marker([0, -90]),
    L.marker([0, -45]),
    L.marker([0, 0]),
    L.marker([0, 45]),
    L.marker([0, 90]),
    L.marker([0, 135])
  ]
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body, #map {
    height: 100%
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

http://embed.plnkr.co/mWKc4M/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The markers will appear on the map if I *pan* the map

Specifically, this behaviour happens only when *dragging* the map (and not when *panning* the map via any other method, e.g. using keyboard shortcuts). This is because, internally, the `worldCopyJump` functionality is [defined inside the Drag handler at `src/map/handler/Map.Drag.js`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/9644fcfcfc6993060d3468292f6ca84ee378b2c0/src/map/handler/Map.Drag.js#L40-L45):

```
// TODO refactor, move to CRS
// @option worldCopyJump: Boolean = false
// With this option enabled, the map tracks when you pan to another "copy"
// of the world and seamlessly jumps to the original one so that all overlays
// like markers and vector layers are still visible.
worldCopyJump: false,
```

(Do note that Leaflet has an explanation of [what map handlers are](https://leafletjs.com/examples/extending/extending-3-controls.html) and how they work)

[As the code stands now](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/handler/Map.Drag.js#L174), the `worldCopyJump` functionality affects only the dragging handler, and works by resetting the drag offset (instead of the map center) every time the map dragging handler is about to be updated:

```
if (map.options.worldCopyJump) {
    this._draggable.on('predrag', this._onPreDragWrap, this);
    map.on('zoomend', this._onZoomEnd, this);

    map.whenReady(this._onZoomEnd, this);
}
/* snip */
_onPreDragWrap: function () {
    // TODO refactor to be able to adjust map pane position after zoom
    var worldWidth = this._worldWidth,
        halfWidth = Math.round(worldWidth / 2),
        dx = this._initialWorldOffset,
        x = this._draggable._newPos.x,
        newX1 = (x - halfWidth + dx) % worldWidth + halfWidth - dx,
        newX2 = (x + halfWidth + dx) % worldWidth - halfWidth - dx,
        newX = Math.abs(newX1 + dx) < Math.abs(newX2 + dx) ? newX1 : newX2;

    this._draggable._absPos = this._draggable._newPos.clone();
    this._draggable._newPos.x = newX;
},
```

So, what to do? An option is to leverage [`wrapLatLng`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-wraplatlng) to reset the map center on every `zoomend` event, e.g.:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(ev){
    map.panTo(map.wrapLatLng(map.getCenter()), {animate: false})
});
```

That should just work. See a [working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/bSYA75OjomarZsHS).

---

As an alternative, consider using https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.RepeatedMarkers , which will create copies of each marker every 360° of longitude.

Comment: See also https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/7197

Comment: Thanks Ivan for multiple solutions! That is exactly what I needed.